# Get all of my project paths and convert them to string to save in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a model with these parameters:

> title - path - parent - position - visible

to create a dynamic and sortable menu (or navigation) from all of my project paths. To do it, I want to get all of the paths and save them to a table and customize them. Then use that as follows:

```
   <li><a href="#{menu.path}"><%= menu.title %></a></li>
```

My problem is that I want to save all of my paths into a model. But how can I get all of the project paths and convert them to strings to save to a database?

For example, I have these paths:

```
/pages/:id
/gallery
/news
etc...
```

and I want to save the paths below in a database:

```
/pages/1
/pages/2
/gallery
/news
```

my route.rb like follow:

```
       resources :pages do
            resources :partners
            resources :galleries
            resources :pages do
               resources :partners
               resources :galleries
            end
        end
        resources :colleges do
            resources :partners
            resources :galleries
            resources :pages do
                resources :partners
                resources :galleries
            end
            resources :groups do
                resources :partners
                resources :galleries 
                resources :pages do
                    resources :partners
                    resources :galleries
                end 
            end
        end
```

Comment: please clarify what you want to do exactly, the question is not clear

Comment: May i ask why you want to store them in the database and not load them dynamically when generating the pages?

Comment: i want create a customizable menu in head of website for admin user. and sort that links and show or hidden a link

Comment: And doing this directly in the models that make up the pages is not working that you need this in an additional model?

Comment: Can you show us how your routes.rb looks like?

Answer (score 1):

So to get to all your routes you need to do like this, assuming your models look like they normally do with this structure in routes.rb:

```
Page.find_each.with_index do |page, page_index|
  page_entry = Entry.create({
    title: '' # whatever makes your title
    path: url_for([page]),
    parent: page_entry,
    position: page_index
    visible: true
  }) 

  page.pages.find_each.with_index do |sub, sub_index|
    sub_entry = Entry.create({
      title: '' # whatever makes your title
      path: url_for([page, sub]),
      parent: page_entry,
      position: sub_index,
      visible: true
    })      

    sub.partners.find_each.with_index do |partner, partner_index|
      Entry.create({
        title: '' # whatever makes your title
        path: url_for([page, sub, partner]),
        parent: sub_entry,
        position: partner_index,
        visible: true
      })
    end
  end
end
```

This is only a example for one "arm" of the nested tree, you can add the others in the same structure as your routes.rb file define them.

However i would suggest not do do this and instead build your views dynamically using the models directly. Because changing Models (for example in the Galler) do not get reflected in your new entries and will for sure cause you a lot of problems in the future unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to make use of named routes.
you should not store href paths in db, but instead name them with variables and create then at initialization.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html